# Setting precision while scaling vectors using preprocessing in scikit learn

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have to calculate Euclidean distance between two vectors , and have to do scaling before i calculate the distances.

```
sample_A= np.array([1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0.008624,-0.002894,0.006471,0.000961,0.007407,-0.004442,-0.00966,-0.003026,0.010202,0.008907,-0.003031,-0.002724,0.002302,0.002171,-0.011219,0.006802,0.004588,0.030068,0.016608,0.021235,0.015706,0.102711,0.053489,0.006902,-0.010042,0.002647,0.036403,-0.010567,0.040207,0.065626,-0.010786,-0.010131,0.080007,-0.046524,-0.08577,0.120587,0.159285,0.058588,0.112184,0.011561])
sample_B = np.array([18,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1.921413,-1.350259,-0.549294,-0.829648,-0.271365,-2.267258,-0.043207,-0.127863,0.46472,0.106202,-0.363018,-0.863932,-1.041068,0.944935,-0.269358,-0.705195,-0.505604,-0.721329,0.603105,-0.619679,-0.461518,0.595048,-0.097054,-1.602379,-0.373747,-0.253988,-0.476779,1.108103,1.428308,1.12896,1.296803,-0.086155,-0.555077,0.347556,0.202161,0.289031,0.676664,-0.318146,0.193779,0.841483])
```

The expected distance between these two points as per requirement is `7.296226771`

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
A_scaled = preprocessing.scale(sample_A)
B_scaled = preprocessing.scale(sample_B)
distance.euclidean(A_scaled,B_scaled)
```

The value i got was `7.713635264892224`

My understanding is this is because of the higher precision that is present while calculating the standard deviation and mean. Is there any way to provide precision while scaling as input to the function or do i have to write a custom scale function.

If so how can i write a custom scale function that applies to the entire numpy array.

Comment: *"The expected distance between these two points as per requirement is 7.296226771"* - based on what?

Comment: based on sample example in the requirement doc that i have got.

Comment: Well, do you know exactly how the value in your requirement doc was calculated? How can you be sure that it is more precise than the result above?

Comment: Yes . I know from the example that the standard deviation calculated had less precision.

Comment: I'm quite sure that the discrepancy between your calculations and the example value has nothing to do with floating point precision. Assuming you're using 64bit floats, the distance value calculated above ought to be accurate to at least 10 decimal places. It could be that 1) there is a mistake in your documentation, 2) the arrays given above are not correct, or 3) you misunderstand how the value in the documentation was calculated.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I will recheck on this.